# no reply from server

Tags: 14.04, wget, https

```
 wget http://10.254.5.225:8080/debs/amd64/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
--2015-07-22 12:59:56--  http://10.254.5.225:8080/debs/amd64/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
Connecting to 10.254.5.225:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
```

On 10.254.5.225 IPtables are off and apache2 service is running
and the debs folder is exported. I have hosted the files and I am able to see the files on the browser

Answer (score 0):

Apache2 defaults the directory structure to `/var/www/html/` folder on your hard drive.  If you want to have that file available, you would put your `debs/amd64` folders in there.

It would look like this on the hard drive:

```
/var/www/html/debs/amd64/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

or, you could put a link there as well, by typing in

```
ln -s /var/www/html/debs /path/to/debs/
```

also, make sure that the file(s) have at least `Read` attributes on the files so that they can be read and downloaded

```
sudo chmod -R +r /path/to/debs/
```

Hope this helps!